# How to pass the second occurrence of a blankspace in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

> Duration       : 00:05:48.73
>
> File Size       61.5M

As you can see the two lines. One of them has a **:** separating the word and the number, the other one has a **blankspace** separating the word and number.
I need to separate the word from the number for both the cases (for : as well as for blankspace).

I used String.Split(':') and String.Split(null). While the String.Split(':') worked, and there were only two items in the array, String.Split(null) resulted in the following items in the array: **File, Size, 61.5M**. So three items. I want to make that into two.

this is the code I'm using:

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^([\p{L}_ ]+):?(.+)$");
Match match = _regex.Match(line);
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
    string value = match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: so you need single regex that can split first line. and second line both? for 1st it should return `Duration` and `00:05:48.73` and for second it should return `File Size` and `61.5M` thats what you need? or regex just to split second line

Comment: [What's wrong with your regex?](https://regex101.com/r/SQk8Iz/1)

Comment: @DeepakSharma new Regex(@"^([\p{L}_ ]+):?(.+)$") this one actually makes me get Duration and 00:05:48.73 in the array, but it doesn't pass for File Size 61.5M. I want the regex to accept both conditions.

Comment: pls see my answer below.. your regex working fine, and do pass both the lines, and return your expected result.  I didn't make any changes in your regex. Just gave the proof your `regex` is working like charm for both the lines.

Comment: @DeepakSharma oh yes it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your split may not work, but if you use the regex you mentioned that should work fine.

Please find the attached fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0apnE

```
    var line1 = "Duration : 00:05:48.73";
    var line2 = "File Size 61.5M";

    Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^([\p{L}_ ]+):?(.+)$");
    Match match = _regex.Match(line1);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string key = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
        string value = match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;

        //call trim to remove extra space around.
        Console.WriteLine(key.Trim());  //Duration
        Console.WriteLine(value.Trim());  //00:05:48.73
    }

    match = _regex.Match(line2);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string key = match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
        string value = match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;

        //call trim to remove extra space around.
        Console.WriteLine(key.Trim());   //File Size
        Console.WriteLine(value.Trim()); //61.5M
    }
```